# high cpu/gpu temerature after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, overheating

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 on a laptop with an Intel i7-4700mq and a Nvidia GTX 770m.

After the fresh installation , everything worked with the Nouveau driver.

After installing the proprietary drivers Nvidia 390(recommended) the CPU started to overheat. 
While using nouveau driver the idle temeperature would be 47 , but with nvidia 390  driver idle temperature is around 61.

I tried to switch to Intel via nvidia-settings prime profiles , and via `prime-select` , but it doesn't work.

The result of `ps auxc | grep -i therm`

```
root         181  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   18:15   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root         963  0.0  0.0 125860  9964 ?        Ssl  18:15   0:00 thermald
```

The output of `sensors`

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +61.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +56.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +56.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +56.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

The output of `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       Driver Version: 440.64       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 770M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
|  0%   62C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    171MiB /  3018MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: 61C is only a tad highish, but you say the fans are running? Have you overclocked your CPU or RAM? Edit your question and show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`. And, if you have lm-sensors installed, if not, install it, and show me `sensors`.

Comment: i've done that,  also if i switch to nouveau driver via software & updates and restart , temp would go back to normal ,  btw i disabled TurboBoost from bios

Comment: You have two different thermal packages installed. `sudo apt-get purge thermald`. Also, Nvidia 418.88 can be downloaded from https://www.geforce.com/drivers. How old is this laptop? Is it very dusty/dirty?

Comment: i clean the laptop and change thermal paste for cpu and gpu regularly . i will uninstall thermlad and upgrade to 418.88 and be back ty tho

Comment: i purged thermld and tried both Nvidia 418 and 440 and still i got the same problem , the only thing that reduce temp for now is going back to nouveau driver ,

Comment: Or just switch to Intel, and only use Nvidia when you need to.

Comment: I guess so, thank you so much btw , Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. If you use a more powerful processor, the temperature will go up, as per the Second Law of Thermodynamics.

Intel has no problem with anything under 100C as per https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75117/intel-core-i7-4700mq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html

[image: Tdescription value of the OP's CPU]

Comment: I'm not sure how could that help . I mean what can one do to get lower temp

Comment: Yes , but it doesn't feel comfortable having the fan running crazy while idle . I doesnt make sense

Comment: If i get it right . Installing nvidia driver would power-on the gpu and make it the primary display device . And due to poor laptops heatsinks/cooling . It would cause the whole package to heat up . I mean is there any way to be using intel gpu with the option to run specific tasks/apps with nvidia gpu ?